# How to find out which char in string is a number?

Tags: java

How to find out if the char in string is a letter or a number?

I.e I have a string "abc2e4", I need to find the ints, square them, and put the answer back in the string (no extra operations with the letters), so the new string would be "abc4e16".

Im incredibly lost with this exercise, so any help would be great :D

Comment: [String#toCharAray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--) and [Character.isDigit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit-char-) will help

Comment: `"abc2e4".replaceAll("\\D","")` will leave you just with digits in the string.

Comment: @JigarJoshi there is no point in using `toCharArray`, because the new string may be longer than the old. `charAt` and a `StringBuilder` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Andy good point.

Answer (score 0):

Java provides a method to check whether a character is a digit. For this you can use [Character.isDigit(char)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit-char-).

```
public static String squareNumbers(String input) {
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char c = input.charAt(i); // get char at index
        if (Character.isDigit(c))  // check if the char is a digit between 0-9
            output.append((int) Math.pow(Character.digit(c, 10), 2)); // square the numerical value
        else
            output.append(c); // keep if not a digit
    }
    return output.toString();
}
```

This will iterate any passed string character by character and square each digit it finds. If for example 2 digits are right next to each other they will be seen as individual numbers and squared each and not as one number with multiple digits.

`squareNumbers("10")` -> `"10"`

`squareNumbers("12")` -> `"14"`

`squareNumbers("abc2e4")` -> `"abc4e16"`

Comment: String concatenation in loop!

Comment: There you go, I've made it explicit.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using *Regular Expression*

```
public static String update(String str) {
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\D+|\\d+");
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    int pos = 0;

    while (matcher.find(pos)) {
        str = matcher.group();
        buf.append(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(0)) ? (int)Math.pow(Integer.parseInt(str), 2) : str);
        pos = matcher.end();
    }

    return buf.toString();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

My logic only squares single digit numbers.

For eg - if you provide input he13llo, the output would be he19llo and not he169llo.

```
 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in) ; 
    String str = in.next() ; 
    String ans = str ; 

    for (int i = 0 ; i < str.length() ; i++)
    {
        char ch = str.charAt(i) ; 
        if((ch - '0' >= 0) && (ch - '9' <= 0))
        {
            int index = i ; 
            int num = ch - '0' ; 
            int square = num * num ; 
            ans = ans.substring(0 ,index) + square  + ans.substring(index+1) ; 
        }
    }
    System.out.println(ans) ; 
 }
```

Comment: String concatenation in loop

Comment: No, in loop - no.

Comment: I'm sorry - I didn't understand your comment Oleg

Comment: Here is a relevant post explaining the issues of string concatenation in java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java

Comment: @Minn this is not relevant, because `for loop` will not be optimized with JVM, but `str1 + str2 + str3` - will

Comment: @oleg.cherednik the answers explain this behavior and the cost it brings

Comment: This is correct link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1